# ClearCase does not show as source control option in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2013

We have Visual Studio 2015 and I'm trying to incorporate ClearCase, which we also have, version 8.0.0.16.

I installed Visual Studio Integration through the Installation Manager.

The most recent Visual Studio version officially supported by IBM is 2013, but the Stack Exchange post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069163/clearcase-in-visual-studio-2015 shows no problem with 2015, so it should work.

When I open Visual Studio, go to tools, then options, then source control, ClearCase is not listed as an option. The options given are GitGIT and Team Foundation.

How do I get it working?

Comment: Sounds like it does not actually support VS2015 have you installed VS2013 to rule that possibility out?

Comment: We had VS2013 and upgraded from that. We will not be going back to it. Installing VS2013 would prove ClearCase functionality, but there were no errors in the ClearCase install and no reason to believe anything would be  deficient. Since it would not cause ClearCase to work with VS2015 and the link provided says it should work without issue, I'm not going to install VS2013 again.

Comment: You followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069163/clearcase-in-visual-studio-2015/34322044#34322044) answer?

Comment: No, I'm going to proceed as if ClearCase is supposed to work with VS2015, as in the link I posted, and I'm not going to mess with VS2013. As I explained, installing VS2013 does not accomplish anything. If it works it doesn't prove anything. If it doesn't work it doesn't prove anything. I am hoping someone who uses ClearCase with Visual Studio regardless of the version, will see my issue and recognize what's wrong.